# Удаляется файл .htaccess с сервера

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, apache

При загрузке файла .htaccess через ftp файл удаляется.
AllowOverride стоит на On
Пытался сам через sudo занести файл но он все равно удаляется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: добавьте опцию: `$ ls -a`

Comment: хорошо. а почему файл .htaccess не работает

Comment: я раньше держал его на виртуальном хосте. уже готовом. а щас решил перенести на вдс. у меня он попросту не хочет работать

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос.